# extract the row having column values length equal to 1 in R

Tags: r, apply

my input data is
df

```
     anger sad joy happy trust disgust
1     1   0   1     2     3       0
2     2   0   0     2     0       3
3     2   2   1     1     1       1
4     0   1   1     1     0       1
```

I want output like this

mydata

```
    anger sad joy happy trust disgust   col
1     1   0   1     2     3       0     trust
2     2   0   0     2     0       3     disgust
```

I want to extract max value colname from each row but output only those rows having only one max value colname and discard all other row with more than one colname.

i tried this

```
d1 <- df[!apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) anyDuplicated(x[x == max(x)])),]
```

but i am getting this

```
    anger sad joy happy trust disgust
1     1   0   1     2     3       0
2     2   0   0     2     0       3
3     2   2   1     1     1       1
```

I don't want third row in the output.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Should the value be 'v2' for the row No.4.  It is showed as 'v3' at one place and 'v2 ' in the `list`

Comment: sry. i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the index of columns for each row after subsetting the rows

```
d1 <- mydata[!apply(mydata[-1], 1, anyDuplicated),]
d1$out <- names(d1)[-1][max.col(d1[-1], 'first')]
d1
#   zone_id v1 v2 v3 v4 out
#1       1 12 15 18 20  v4
#3       3 31 28 14  2  v1
#4       4 12 16  9  5  v2
#5       5  5 18 10 12  v2
```

#### Update

If the OP wanted to remove only the duplicate values of max values, then replace the first line with

```
d1 <- mydata[!apply(mydata[-1], 1, function(x) anyDuplicated(x[x == max(x)])),]
```

#### Update2

Based on the newdataset by the OP, we don't need to remove the first column  as it is not an id column

```
d2 <- mydata1[!apply(mydata1, 1, function(x) anyDuplicated(x[x == max(x)])),]

d2$out <- names(d2)[max.col(d2, 'first')]
d2
#  anger sad joy happy trust disgust     out
#1     1   0   1     2     3       0   trust
#2     2   0   0     2     0       3 disgust
```

#### data

```
mydata1 <- structure(list(anger = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 0L), sad = c(0L, 0L, 2L,
  1L), joy = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), happy = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), trust = c(3L,
  0L, 1L, 0L), disgust = c(0L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("anger", "sad", 
 "joy", "happy", "trust", "disgust"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), 
 class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks. it's working. But in this question only max occurring twice or thrice in a row .If value other max value occurring twice or thrice then how to proceed with code.For this, i edited my question.

Comment: @SWETASWAIN  This was not part of your original question.  It should be posted as a new question.

Comment: @SWETASWAIN  It is not clear about your question because in the first step, `ie. the `apply` with `anyDuplicated`, it will look for any values that are duplicated and not only `max` to filter the rows

Comment: Sry for the inconvenience. I missed that part of my question. Because of this condition, i am not getting exact result

Comment: @SWETASWAIN  Your expected output in the post is same as the one  I am getting.  Please update your post with a relevant example and expected output

Comment: Yay, u right but I want to remove row having duplicated max values only.If u could help. Please help me.

Comment: I changed my output. I having duplicated values in a row but they were not max values, row with duplicated max values were removed only. If still not understandable. i will provide u another example.

Comment: @SWETASWAIN  Based on your new input, I get `names(d1)[-1][max.col(d1[-1], 'first')]#
[1] "v4" "v1" "v2" "v2"`

Comment: i am still not getting the desired result. I think there is some problem with my dataset.

Comment: @SWETASWAIN  Could you check the `str(yourdata)` to find if there are any non-numeric column class?  Also, if possible, use `dput` to update the example, i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata, 10)))` and paste the output in your post for understanding the structure of your data

Comment: this output of :       dput(droplevels(head(df, 4)))
structure(list(anger = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 0L), sad = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 
1L), joy = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), happy = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), trust = c(3L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), disgust = c(0L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("anger", 
"sad", "joy", "happy", "trust", "disgust"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: output is :                                                                                                            anger sad joy happy trust disgust     out
1     1   0   1     2     3       0   trust
2     2   0   0     2     0       3 disgust
3     2   2   1     1     1       1     sad                                                                          I don't want the last row...

Comment: @SWETASWAIN It is better you update your post with that output as it is difficult to copy/paste from the comments

Comment: @SWETASWAIN  What about the third row.  It also have two 2's which are the maximum values in that row i.e. `2   2   1     1     1       1`

Comment: yay I don't want third row in output as it has two 2s as it is the max values.

Comment: @SWETASWAIN  Based on the new data, you don't need to remove the 1st column as it is also included `d1 <- mydata[!apply(mydata, 1, function(x) anyDuplicated(x[x == max(x)])),]` But I failed to understand why the third row is not removed

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
  mydata %>%
  select(-zone_id) %>%
  mutate(mx = do.call(pmax, (.))) %>%
  select(mx) %>%
  cbind(mydata) %>%
  mutate( flg = rowSums(. == mx)) %>%
  filter(flg ==2) %>%
  select(-flg) %>%
  gather(key = out, value= v, -mx, -zone_id) %>%
  filter(mx == v) %>%
  select(zone_id, mx, out) %>%
  left_join(mydata)
```

which gives:

```
  zone_id mx out v1 v2 v3 v4
1       3 31  v1 31 28  2  2
2       4 16  v2  1 16  9  1
3       5 18  v2  5 18 10 12
4       1 20  v4 12 15 18 20
```